# How to do Kolmogorov 2 sample test in r?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov

How to do Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test in R?
Which packages to use?
I searched on the web and then found **ks2Test ** to use to do 2 sample test. But I couldnot find the packages for it. I used package

```
dgof
```

and

```
 fHTEST
```

but still not working. Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

`> ?ks2.test No documentation for ‘ks2.test’ in specified packages and libraries: you could try ‘??ks2.test’` and when I use

```
ks2.test
```

it says no result found.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `ks.test` is in the **stats** package (no need to load it).

```r
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- runif(30)
# Do x and y come from the same distribution?
ks.test(x, y)
```

Comment: One thing I would like to ask , in presence of ties R gives an warning but still calculates the p-value. In that case what does it do ?

Comment: @PAC-MAN I don't know, the doc does not say too much about this issue. Maybe make a Google search.